# Looking for an anime with boy who wields a sword that can change size

Tags: story-identification, anime

Trying to look for an anime that was played on tv in the 1990s that features as its main character a boy who wields a sword that can change size (conceptually similar to Sun Wukong's staff weapon in the Journey to the West story).

I watched it in Taiwan. Mid 1990s. About 1994 or 1995. I cannot remember for sure, since I was about 4 or 5 years old at the time. I also do not remember what channel it was on, since I probably had no concept of television channels at the time. In case there is need of clarification, the anime was japanese, although I remembered it being dubbed, because the ending credits had japanese text, which I was able to differentiate at the time despite being illiterate.

Based on the art style, the anime might have been made in the 1980s or possibly earlier. If I remember correctly, characters in this show seem to wear clothing that might have had Greco-Roman cultural undertones.

The only scene I remember more clearly was one in which the main character's mother was abducted by another female character, who after rendering his mother unconscious, placed her body in front of a large flying eyeball creature, after which the eyeball creature sucked the mother through its pupil and flew away.

Comment: Hello! When you say you watched it on tv in the 1990's, in which country was it? Early or Late 90's?

Comment: It was in Taiwan. Mid 1990s. About 1994 or 1995. I cannot remember for sure, since I was about 4 or 5 years old at the time. I also do not remember what channel it was on, since I probably had no concept of television channels at the time. In case there is need of clarification, the anime was japanese, although I remembered it being dubbed, because the ending credits had japanese text, which I was able to differentiate at the time despite being illiterate.